# Date with a time zone specified as a string is parsed as naive

Tags: python, datetime

I'm curious why the timezone in this example, `GMT`, is not parsed as a valid one:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> import pytz
>>> b = 'Mon, 3 Oct 2016 21:24:17 GMT'
>>> fmt = '%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %Z'
>>> datetime.strptime(b, fmt).astimezone(pytz.utc)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: astimezone() cannot be applied to a naive datetime
```

Doing the same with a `-0700` instead of `GMT` and `%z` instead of `%Z` in the format works just fine.

What's the proper way to parse dates ending in string time zones if not this?

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted...

Answer (score 0):

Use `.replace()` method with `datetime` object to update the time zone info.

```
>>> datetime.strptime(b, fmt).replace(tzinfo=pytz.utc)
datetime.datetime(2016, 10, 3, 21, 24, 17, tzinfo=<UTC>)
```

Since you mentioned, `.astimezone()` is working with `%Z` instead of `%s` in the format string. Even though there is `z` in both the formatting (difference in just case), but they are totally different in terms of what they represent.

As per the [`strftime`](http://strftime.org/)'s directive document:

> **%z** :  UTC offset in the form +HHMM or -HHMM (empty string if the the object is naive).
>
> **%Z** :  Time zone name (empty string if the object is naive).

Comment: That simply replaces the timezone with UTC. I want to *adjust* it to UTC. Also, curiously, if you use EST instead of GMT in the example above, your `replace` command fails as well, not sure why.

Comment: I don't really understand your edit. I get that they're different, that's why I noted that it works with one but not the other.